# How do I add a tagname on a entity in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a mc map and I want a zombiefied piglin walking over some blocks. I found out how to make him move, but I need a tagname for him, so it would only affect him and not the other piglins. How can I summon a entity with a NBT? I have searched almost every site and just can't find it. I tried CustomName but then the entity was not regonised. (Sorry for bad Englisch, I'm from Netherlands). Hope someone could help me...

Comment: Is there anything that you've already tried?  Can you show us what commands you're using?  You'll find that others will be more receptive of your question if you've shown some effort in solving it yourself.  Please edit your question with the extra details.

Comment: You could just name the piglin with a nametag, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_Wiki) is definitely the first place you should look for command help. If you haven't heard of it, trust me, it is a lifesaver in commands.

The command you'll want to use is the [`/tag`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/tag) commmand. This lets you tag your mob with a recognizable text string and reference it again afterwards using the same string. Like this:

```
/tag @e[name="THE_PIGLIN",type=piglin] add movingPiglin
```

To reference the tagged entity at the end, you can learn how [target selectors](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors) work, specifically the `tag =` argument.

```
@e[tag=movingPiglin]
```

Comment: Thxx, it helped